# how to reference the tool that is set in the global tool configuration in Jenkins in the jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have set up cmake tool under the Global tool configuration in Jenkins. I tried to reference it in my jenkinsfile but the build is giving this error:

```
'cmake is not a recognised command'.
```

This is how i am referencing it in the jenkinsfile :

```
stage('run CMake')
    {
         bat '''
         mkdir build
         cd build
         cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=E:/local/boost_1_64_0 -DOPC_UA_FRAMEWORK_ROOT=E:/local/bhi-opcuaframework-1.2.0-win32
```

And this is the configuration of CMake in the Jenkins dashboard:

[image]

This is how my setting in global tool config looks like.

How do i correctly reference the tool in the pipeline?

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `tool` step:

```
stage('run CMake')
{
     def cmakePath = tool 'CMake'
     bat """
     mkdir build
     cd build
     ${cmakePath}\\cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=...
     """
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you have cmake installed on jenkins master? if not try to install it using installer.

Check the jenkins cmake wiki page screenshot check below, install it using installer if you haven't already check this help:

- [Tool Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tool+Configuration)
- [Global Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Global+Configuration)
- [CMake Build Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CMake+Build+Configuration)

Comment: I have already cmake installed on Jenkins master. What I really would like to know is if I have called this global tool setting appropriately in the jenkinsfile. Please take a look at my jenkinsfile part. is the commad 'cmake' enough for jenkins to know that the tool is configured in its global tool configuration and to pick the path of cmake from there? or do we have to add something like tool = cmake within the jenkinsfile for jenkins to understamnd that we are refering to the global settings? . Do you know?